Server Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
Sometimes I get this error and only thing that helps is cancelling dev server and running npm run dev again.

You can create context server side but they only can be consumed client side.
Context in server component

I am not using context on that page

@steve123 so please provide some code^^ Will be better to find out
